# how much is CPU usage considered high on linux server

Tags: php, linux, cpu-usage

I'm running a few PHP job which fetches 100th thousands of data from a webservice and insert them to database. These jobs take up the CPU usage of the server.

My question is, how much is it considered high?

When i do a "top" command on linux server, 
it seems like 77% .. It will go up to more than 100% if i run more jobs simultaneously. It seems high to me, (does more than 100% means it is running on the 2nd CPU ?)

```
28908 mysql     15   0  152m  43m 5556 S 77.6  4.3   2099:25 mysqld             
 7227 apache    15   0  104m  79m 5964 S  2.3  7.8   4:54.81 httpd
```

This server is also has also webpages/projects hosted in it. The hourly job since to be affecting the server as well as the other web project's loading time.

If high, is there any way of making it more efficient on the CPU?

Anyone can enlighten?

Comment: Yes, it's 100% *per* CPU. It is *constant* CPU load that is normally the problem (but it's only a problem if it's a problem, keeping "slack" is good so that extra processing power is *available* when needed, also a CPU that idles more can run cooler/draws less power). If the PHP job completes within the functional requirements and doesn't violate any usage guidelines or starve other processes I'd say "good enough". To make the process more efficient would require a detailed review/profiling and analysis.

Comment: Er, *per core*. Not sure how hyperthreading or equivalent fits in though.

Answer (score 2):

A better indicator is the [load average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_average), if I simplify, it is the amount of waiting tasks because of insufficient resources.

You can access it in the `uptime` command, for example: `13:05:31 up 6 days, 22:54,  5 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.04, 0.06`. The 3 numbers at the end are the load averages for the last minute, the last 5 minutes and the last 15 minutes. If it reaches `1.00`, (no matter of the number of cores) it is that *something it waiting*.

Comment: my load average is ..load average: 0.20, 0.23, 0.18

Comment: it seams you don't experience resource starvation (neither processor, disk nor network for the last 15 minutes). Your computer don't have difficulties to do its job.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say 77% is definitly high.

There are probably many ways to make the job more efficient, (recursive import), but not much info given.

A quick fix would be invoking the script with the nice cmd,
and add a few sleeps to stretch the load over time.

I guess you also saturate the network during import, so can you split up the job it would prevent your site from stalling.

regards,
/t

Comment: any useful sites, or keywords that i can research on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always nice your tasks

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nice

With the command nice you can give proccesses more or less priority

Answer (score 0):

> These jobs take up the CPU usage of the server.
>   My question is, how much is it considered high?

That is entirely subjective. On computing nodes, the CPU usage is pretty much 100% per core all the time. Is that high? No, not at all, it is proper use of hardware that has been bought for money.

Answer (score 0):

Nice won't help much, since it's mysql that's occupying your cpu,
putting nice on a php-client as in

```
nice -10 php /home/me/myjob.php
```

won't make any significant difference.

Better to split up the job so smaller parts, call your php-script
from cron and build it like

```
<?
ini_set("max_execution_time", "600")
//
//1. get the file from remote server, in chunks to avoid net saturation
$fp = fopen('http://example.org/list.txt');
$fp2 = fopen('local.txt','w');
while(!feof($fp)) {
  fwrite($fp2,fread($fp,10000));
  sleep(5);
}
fclose($fp/fp2);

while(!eof(file) {
  //read 1000 lines
  //do insert..
  sleep(10);
}
//finished, now rename to .bak, log success or whatever...
```